# Recruiter asks you out for coffee, what is their intent?

Tags: recruitment, networking

A while back, I had two different female recruiters ask me out for coffee, regardless of whether or not they had any available positions that match my qualifications.

What is their intent? Is this a recent kind of recruitment?

Comment: They want to ask you a few questions face to face.  Since your meeting with them is during office hours, they most likely have to justify their time to their management, so don't expect anything from them that's not job related. It's a business coffee break. No fun and games.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- They are looking to put a face to your name so you'll be more memorable
- They are looking to get a better idea of your personality so when they *do* have positions to fill they'll know you better and can decide whether you'll be a good fit
- They are trying to establish a trust relationship with you so you'll be more likely to work with them in the future
- They are networking; you could potentially become a source of referrals for them

Recruiters' invitations are full of ulterior motives but they're professional in nature.

Comment: Or perhaps they just want an excuse for a coffee break

Comment: "They are looking to put a face to your name so you'll be more memorable" goes both ways. They want YOU to remember THEM as well. Recruiters are a dime a dozen in some professions.

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary.  It sounds like a common multi-level marketing scheme set-up.  Most people - once in the "we're just having coffee" situation - are too polite to break contact, so they just sit there and listen to the pitch.

Comment: yea I had one of those lol waste of time for sure. Not sure why this sort of companies still alive.